# Is it recommended to git merge and push or to just copy the files of a library that I want to use in my project and then push?

Tags: git, github

I'm writing a program which is public on GitHub, and uses two Python libraries that are also public on GitHub. I can just copy them into my project (keeping their license of course), commit and push but I can also do it this way: add them as remote repositories and checkout them to local branches, merge them into my working branch and then commit and push. The second way retains the previous history and authors but uses more space.

Comment: Neither of the above, you should add them as a submodule, this way you'll be able to keep them in sync in your project if they're updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is beter to use git subtree merge - it also allows you to pull updates from merged repositories

more in manual http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html

Comment: As [CharlesB points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579989/is-it-recommended-to-git-merge-and-push-or-to-just-copy-the-files-of-a-library-t#comment27340159_18579989), using `git submodule` is also an option.

Comment: Thanks, I have started reading about subtree and submodule